# How to trigger event when mouse is clicked AND a key is held down?

Tags: glut, keyboard-events

Is there any way to detect if a key is being held down while inside of the glutMouseFunc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Store a globally-accessible list of what keys are currently held down. Then read that list in your MouseFunc.

Note that the mouse callback already gets the control key state (shift/alt/ctrl), so you generally don't need to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to set a state variable when the key is held down and change it back when the key is released. I have the mouse function check if the program is in the right state. Also glutIgnoreKeyRepeat is helpful when trying to hold down keys